# Why carousel picture does not change automatically?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to change my carousel picture, but I could not solve this problem. I have already seen several examples but I find no error in my code. I wonder if some of you find a mistake in it. Thank you

```
        <!--Imagenes interactivas-->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="assets/images/menu1.jpg" alt="Hamburguesa">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/images/menu2.jpg" alt="Frutas">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/images/menu3.jpg" alt="Pasta">
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

    <!-- Termino Imagenes interactivas -->
```

Comment: are you already include `bootstrap.min.js` ?

Comment: Yes, I have it down below that code  like this                                               <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: what you see in browser console?
try to remove the last item `<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>`

Comment: I just tried and still the same. This is how it look (The photo does not change even if you click the side of the photo) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzQa5GXCpbBTTVdVWnJ5X0ItWU0

Comment: have you try my answer? It's possibly the `javascript` just not linked properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try your code just work fine, just verify that `jquery-1.12.min.js` loaded properly. Because in order to have behaviour that you expect, you need `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` delivered on your *browser runtime*

Or add there script bellow :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so you don't mind accept my answer as the correct one right?

Comment: nvm, just never give up :)